# What does "popped" mean in this phrase?

Tags: meaning

I watched "Zootopia" and heard  this phrase:

> I popped the weasel!

I don't get its meaning. I can't find what it means in the dictionary.

Comment: It is a reference to the rhyme, "Pop goes the weasel" and presumably refers to the noise pop.

Comment: Look up "pop goes the weasel".

Comment: If you have a look at the Wikipedia page for the rhyme, "[Pop! Goes the Weasel](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pop_Goes_the_Weasel)" it seems that the exact meaning is obscured by history.

Comment: Also read [this EL&U answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/356324/184766) which guesses at the origin of the weasel popping; a weasel is a type of yarn spinning machine that would, every once in a while, make a popping noise.

Answer (score 2):

Pop is police slang for [*arrest*](http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-definition-of/pop), as well as *kill* (with a firearm):

> **pop** verb - transitive
>
> to arrest.
>
> - The cops popped him in front of the club.

The Online Slang Dictionary

"I popped the weasel" is also an allusion to the nursery rhyme [*Pop Goes the Weasel*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pop_Goes_the_Weasel), as others have said.

Comment: So you're asserting that in Pop Goes the Weasel, 'pop' is alluding to 'arrest'?

Comment: @BladorthinTheGrey Now where did I say that? If you wish to assume that I implied it, that is up to you.

Comment: It seems that you are saying that in the film they are talking about an arrest (I haven't seen it but presume that fits in the context) and I then wondered if that then extended to cover the original rhyme. If you do think there is evidence of the rhyme alluding to an arrest then Wikipedia is in need of an update.

Comment: @BladorthinTheGrey Well, if others complain about my sloppy writing, I'll amend my answer.

Comment: @BladorthinTheGrey [*Pop! Goes the Weasel*](http://www.scottish-country-dancing-dictionary.com/dance-crib/pop-goes-the-weasel.html) is also the name of a Scottish country dance, but that hardly seems to be relevant here.

Comment: Does the dance have any relation to the rhyme? It seems like something you could jig to.

Comment: @BladorthinTheGrey I could have omitted the reference to the nursery rhyme that you (and others) picked up on, but that would leave my answer incomplete, in my opinion, given that the question is about a children's cartoon film. This sounds like a case of sour grapes to me.

Comment: Sorry, I just wanted confirmation about whether this could be the meaning of the 'pop' since I'm curious. I'm going to prepare a question on the subject since most of the sources I can find are uncertain.

Comment: @BladorthinTheGrey I thought that you were being polemical. I have no idea what *pop* means in the nursery rhyme. I doubt that it means *arrest*, or anything akin to it.

Comment: According to [phrase finder](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/pop-goes-the-weasel.html), it probably has no real meaning in the song.